# Error pushing a local project to a new project on Git

Tags: git, gitlab

I am setting up a new project on my gitlab but is giving me a fatal error. As I am new on git I just followed all the instructions provided on the first page of the repository when created the project, specifically in the section "Push an existing folder" that is what I am trying to do.

I followed the next steps:

```
1- created a SSH Key.
1.2- add the SSH Key to my account
2- git init
3- git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:<user>/<project>.git
4- git add .
5- git commit -m "Initial commit"
6- git push -u origin master
```

When I run the last comand (6) I get this error on my console:

````
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.```
````

Comment: There is a missing step: "1.5 import the SSH public key into your GitLab account". Everything else is correct.

Comment: If you run `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` does it say Welcome <your username>!? If you have multiple SSH keys, it may be using the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.``
```

1. You have created ssh key - but have you added it to your account in gitlab?

   - You can verify if your ssh key is installed successfully using this command:

     ```
     ssh-keyscan gitlab.com
     ```
2. Have you granted permission to the specific project?

   - Try to clone the project and see if you can clone it using the ssh url from gitlab.com

Comment: I did adding the SSH Key to my account. I just forget to write it down on my steps list. I also already try to see if I granted permissions to that specific project by clonning the project but is shows the same error, so I think that may be the problem, could you explain how to do it? I just google it but I do not see anything I can try

Comment: Here is how to set it up: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: I was just using the wrongs SSH Key.
What I did to solve this was to edit the config file `(~/./ssh/config)` and stablished what key to use -in this case, the one I was using on my profile and I had created before-.

It worked for me.